# REGEX unique numbers delimited by comma

Tags: regex

I am trying to validate a comma separated list of numbers 1-31 unique (not repeating).

i.e.

- 2,4,6,7,1 is valid input.
- 2,2,6 is invalid
- 2 is valid
- 2, is invalid
- 1,2,3,4,15,6,7,31 is valid
- 1,2,3,4,15,6,7,32 is invalid
- 20,15,3

  I tried
  `^((([0]?[1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(3[01]))(?!([0]?[1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(3[01])*,\\1(?!([0]?[1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(3[01]))` but it's accepting repeating numbers

Comment: Why don't you split the list of numbers by the delimiter and then check for duplicates in the iterable object?

Comment: does your list have a fixed number of numbers that it can't have more than? , in any case I would suggest you break the problem down instead of doing it all in 1 regex: maybe one regex to verify that the comma number format is correct, then split on comma and verify that the numbers are unique by looping through it with a hashset

Comment: this feels like splitting into a list and doing actions on there would be better, not really a good use of regex

Comment: What is your regex flavor?

Comment: I don't think regex have something to do here.
What's the programming language are you using ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a number range that exceeds 1 digit, just add word boundary's around
the capture group and the back reference.
This *isolates* a complete number.

This particular one is numb range 1-31

```
 ^                                       # BOS
 (?!                                     # Validate no dups
      .* 
      (                                       # (1 start)
           \b 
           (?: [1-9] | [1-2] \d | 3 [0-1] )        # number range 1-31
           \b 
      )                                       # (1 end)
      .* 
      \b \1 \b 
 )
 (?: [1-9] | [1-2] \d | 3 [0-1] )        # Unrolled-loop, match 1 to many numb's
 (?:                                     # in the number range 1-31
      , 
      (?: [1-9] | [1-2] \d | 3 [0-1] )
 )*
 $                                       # EOS
```

```js
    var data = [
      '2,4,6,7,1',
      '2,2,6',
      '2,30,16,3',
      '2,',
      '1,2,3,2',
      '1,2,2,3',
      '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8'
      ];
      
      data.forEach(function(str) {
        document.write(str + ' gives ' + /^(?!.*(\b(?:[1-9]|[1-2]\d|3[0-1])\b).*\b\1\b)(?:[1-9]|[1-2]\d|3[0-1])(?:,(?:[1-9]|[1-2]\d|3[0-1]))*$/.test(str) + '<br/>');
      });
```

Comment: You are a genius Thanks again. And if you have any tutorial I would appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

I totally agree that there are much better ways than regex to look for duplicates, but if you must do this as regex, here's a way (depending on your regex flavor).

See on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/EBW0IP/2) (I have made it multiline and extended just for testing and readability).

```
^
(?!.*\b(\d+)\b.*\b\1\b)
(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])
(,(0?\d|[12][0-9]|3[01]))*
$
```

Explanation:

- `(?!.*\b(\d+)\b.*\b\1\b)` is a negative lookahead to ensure there are no duplicates
- `(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])` matches the first number
- `(,(0?\d|[12][0-9]|3[01]))*` matches any more

Note: updated to use word boundaries - based on answer from @sln

Answer (score 2):

I have created a pattern that can do this.

The pattern:`^((?!(\d+),[^\n]*\b\2\b)([1-9]\b|[1-2]\d|3[0-1])(,(?1))?)$`

A [demo](https://regex101.com/r/JN7Kti/2).

A short description.

- `^` - matches start of a line
- `(?!(\d+),[^\n]*\b\2\b)` - Looks ahead to ensure the next number is not repeated

  - `(\d+)` - grab next number
  - `,[^\n]*` - a comma followed by anything but a new line
  - `\b\2\b` - The next number again repeated
- `([1-9]\b|[1-2]\d|3[0-1])` - Checks next number between 1-31

  - `[1-9]\b` - Checks for single digit. Boundary used so to prevent two digit numbers matching.
  - `[1-2]\d` - Checks for 10-29
  - `3[0-1]` - Checks for 30,31
- `(,(?1))?)` If followed by comma recurse on main pattern to check if next number is repeated.
- `,` - checks followed by acomma
- `(?1)` - recurses on main pattern.
- `$` - End of line

Updated: Forgot to check 1-31