# Regex to match only unique name separated by comma

Tags: python, regex, expression

I'm using Regular Expression to check the validity of a string.
In particular I want the test pass if the String contains **unique uppercase name** (one or more), eventually seprated by **comma**.

Each name lenght should be between **3** and **20**.

Accepted strings:

> JOHN,MARK,EDDIE
>
> JOHN

NOT Accepted strings:

> JOHN,
>
> JOHN MARK
>
> **JOHN**,MARK,EDDIE,**JOHN**

I'm using the following Regex that ensure that names must be separated by comma (if more than one), but how can I tell that names should be unique?

```
^([A-Z]{3,20})(,[A-Z]{3,20})*$
```

Comment: That's not something that can easily done with a regex. Use a regex to parse the valid names and then check for uniqueness separately.

Comment: I agree with @glibdud, you could process the lines using `split(',')`, then match names and check the unique-ness of each list

Comment: Thank you for your suggestes, I know that at worst, I'll split the string, but I'd like to achieve that with regex, if possible. For numbers I saw this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45946266/regex-unique-numbers-delimited-by-comma

So it seems possible

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/bX1S5k/7

Comment: What about `JEAN-FRANÇOIS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [negative lookahead](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-20) that [quotes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-18) a [matched name](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-17):

```
r'(([a-z]+),?(?!.*\2))+'
```

The `(?!.*\2)` part ensures that the matched name does not occur later on. This serves as an example for how to use negative lookahead. The complete regex as per OP requirements is:

```
re.match(r'^(([A-Z]{3,20})(?![A-Z,]*,\2,),)+$', string + ',')
```

Note that this tests against `string + ','`, i.e. an artificial comma appended, to avoid messing with two different groups for first and subsequent parts.

I suppose the negative lookahead is short-circuiting in a sense that it fails as soon as it encounters a match. That means worst case performance should be O(N^2). We can check that by generating strings that only contain unique names and measure the regex performance. The quadratic fit gives `t = a*N**2 + c` and `a = 0.06 us, c = 3 us`.

[image: Timing plot]

#### Code

```
from random import choice, sample
from string import ascii_lowercase as lowercase
import re
import time

N = 500
data = [None] * N
for i in range(N):
    length = choice(range(3, 21))
    x = ''.join(sample(lowercase, length))
    while sample in data:
        length = choice(range(3, 21))
        x = ''.join(sample(lowercase, length))
    data[i] = x

pattern = re.compile(r'^(([a-z]+),?(?!.*\2))+$')
timings = []
for i in range(2, N+1):
    print('Begin iteration. ', end='', flush=True)
    string = ','.join(data[:i])
    print(f'Run for {i} unique names (lenght = {len(string)}) ... ', end='', flush=True)
    t1 = time.clock()
    m = re.match(pattern, string)
    t2 = time.clock()
    print('done.', end='', flush=True)
    assert m is not None
    timings.append(t2 - t1)
    print(' End iteration.', flush=True)
```

Comment: Interesting - I was convinced this would run in O(number of names ^ 2) time, but it seems quite zippy on my machine even for large inputs. Maybe negative lookaheads are faster than I give them credit for...

Comment: @Kevin I suppose negative lookahead is short-circuiting so only worst case performance should be O(N^2). I quickly checked with some data and it seems to be the case. However I also observed some weird behavior, when running the script multiple times, sometimes for larger N the script would get stuck completely (I had to interrupt it); I printed out during the loop so I could observe the matching getting slower and slower and then suddenly for some N it would just get stuck. From the prints I can also see it is the `match` function. Not sure what is the reason for that. Maybe you have an idea?

Comment: @a_guest your pattern accept "john,mark,". If there is no subsequent name, the comma must not be present

Comment: @RedSparrow As per your question it appeared that you only wanted to know how to check if matched names are unique, not how to deal with trailing commas. Anyway I added a complete example for the corresponding regex.

Answer (score 0):

What you might do is first find the valid strings using your regex without the capturing groups:

`^[A-Z]{3,20}(?:,[A-Z]{3,20})*$`

If the string is valid, then you can split on a comma, and compare the length of the items against the length of the items by using a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) to make them unique.
If those values match, then your string is valid.

For example

```
import re
strings = ["JOHN,MARK,EDDIE", "JOHN", "JOHN,", "JOHN MARK", "JOHN,MARK,EDDIE,JOHN"]

for s in strings:
    m = re.match("^[A-Z]{3,20}(?:,[A-Z]{3,20})*$", s)

    if m:
        parts = s.split(',')
        res = len(parts) == len(set(parts))
        print("{}:{}".format(s, res))
```

Result

```
JOHN,MARK,EDDIE:True
JOHN:True
JOHN,MARK,EDDIE,JOHN:False
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FwQgDH/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/7GAaLa)